# How to solve this unique SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle, database

I have the following tables:

**Student**(Sid,Sname) Primary key: {sid}
**Course**(cid,cname,duration,fee) Primary key:{cid}
**Enrolled**(sid,cid) Foreighn key: {sid,cid}

> Query: Find the maximum fees paid by each student where a student can
>   enroll in different courses.

My attempt:

```
SELECT ssid, max(fee) as MAX_FEES from (Select sid as ssid, C.cid asccid, 
fee from Course C,Enrolled E where C.cid = E.cid) group by
rollup(ssid,ccid,fee)
```

However, this doesn't gives the desired output appropriately. How to output only the Highest fees paid by each student?

Answer (score 1):

try

`SELECT max(c.fee) from course c, student s, enrolled e where s.sid=e.sid and e.cid=c.cid group by e.sid;`

Comment: Thanks, I think we don't need the student table. `SELECT e.sid as Student_id,max(c.fee)as MAX_FEES from course c, enrolled e where e.cid=c.cid group by e.sid` seems to work just fine :)

Comment: It was off the top of my head :D but you are right there is no need for student table

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say if you also needed to list the students who are not enrolled in any course, so I'll provide one more solution:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
  sid NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  sname VARCHAR2(40)
);

CREATE TABLE course (
  cid NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
  cname VARCHAR2(40),
  duration NUMBER,
  fee NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE enrolled (
  sid NUMBER,
  cid NUMBER,
  PRIMARY KEY (sid, cid),
  FOREIGN KEY (sid) REFERENCES student (sid),
  FOREIGN KEY (cid) REFERENCES course (cid)
);

INSERT INTO student (sid, sname) VALUES (1, 'John');
INSERT INTO student (sid, sname) VALUES (2, 'Peter');
INSERT INTO student (sid, sname) VALUES (3, 'Jake');

INSERT INTO course (cid, cname, duration, fee) VALUES (1, 'Math', 1, 1000);
INSERT INTO course (cid, cname, duration, fee) VALUES (2, 'Physics', 1, 1500);

INSERT INTO enrolled (sid, cid) VALUES (1, 1); -- John taking Math
INSERT INTO enrolled (sid, cid) VALUES (1, 2); -- John taking Physics

-- Peter being lazy

INSERT INTO enrolled (sid, cid) VALUES (3, 1); -- Jake taking Math
COMMIT;

-- not taking lazy (not taking any courses) students under account
SELECT s.sid, MAX(c.fee)
  FROM student s
    JOIN enrolled e ON (e.sid = s.sid)
    JOIN course c ON (e.cid = c.cid)
GROUP BY s.sid
;

-- all students
SELECT s.sid, NVL(MAX(c.fee), 0)
  FROM student s
    LEFT JOIN enrolled e ON (e.sid = s.sid)
    LEFT JOIN course c ON (e.cid = c.cid)
GROUP BY s.sid
;
```